# Using NSAffineTransform to rotate NSImage results in a file twice the size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, image-rotation, nsaffinetransform

I'm using the following code to flip (rotate by 180 degrees) an `NSImage`.
But the new image is twice the size (MBs, not dimensions) of the original when saved to disk. I want it to be approximately the same as the original. How can I accomplish this?

```
NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[[_imageView image] TIFFRepresentation]];
NSImage *img = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSMakeSize(imageRep.pixelsWide, imageRep.pixelsHigh)];
[img lockFocus];
NSAffineTransform *rotator = [NSAffineTransform transform];
[rotator translateXBy:imageRep.pixelsWide yBy:imageRep.pixelsHigh];
[rotator scaleXBy:-1 yBy:-1];
[rotator concat];
[imageRep drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageRep.pixelsWide, imageRep.pixelsHigh)];
[img unlockFocus];
```

Code I'm using to save image to disk :

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:[img TIFFRepresentation] attributes:nil];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: TIFF has image compression options, perhaps that is the issue.

Comment: Is the source image also a TIFF? TIFF is a beautiful image format but pretty verbose compared to JPEGs or PNGs, so this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know the root cause of this, but one work around is to save to the JPEG representation instead of the TIFF. The method I wrote is as follows :

```
- (void)CompressAndSaveImg:(NSImage *)img ToDiskAt:(NSString *)path WithCompressionFactor:(float)value{
    NSData *imgData = [img TIFFRepresentation];
    NSBitmapImageRep *imgRep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imgData];
    NSNumber *compressionFactor = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value];
    NSDictionary *imageProps = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:compressionFactor forKey:NSImageCompressionFactor];
    imgData = [imgRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:imageProps];
    [imgData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

You can play around the with the `WithCompressionFactor:(float)value` parameter, but `0.75` works fine for me.